# What wavelength should a laser beam have to not interact with the dust in the air for the laser emitter location not to be possibly detected?

Tags: laser, atmospheric-science, dissipation

What wavelength should a laser beam have to not interact with the dust in the air for the laser emitter location not to be possibly detected by any kind of wave detectors? What is the quantitative connection between detection with the laser beam intensity?

Answer (score 2):

If the wavelength of the laser is longer than the size of the dust particles, the laser light will diffract around them rather than scattering. So an infrared laser would have less dust scattering than a visible laser, and a microwave laser (maser) less still.

Note that an observer which is larger than the laser’s wavelength can always identify the source direction, by standing in the beam and looking for a bright spot.